# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo… java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, nullpointerexception

OK, so the problem I'm having occurs when the **startGame** button is pressed. The app crashes when the button is pressed. The activity is instantiated in the manifest so I'm not sure where the error is. The code for the intent is a copy of the other one (which works) so I have no clue where I went wrong.

Error Log:

> 02-25 14:46:51.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1261): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   02-25 14:46:51.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1261): Process: com.example.hegemony, PID: 1261
>   02-25 14:46:51.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1261): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hegemony/com.example.hegemony.PlayerTurn}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.hegemony"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



    <activity
        android:name="com.example.hegemony.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name="com.example.hegemony.StartScreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.hegemony.STARTSCREEN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity 
        android:name="com.example.hegemony.SetupHomeScreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.hegemony.SETUPHOMESCREEN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.hegemony.SetupPlayer"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.hegemony.SETUPPLAYER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.hegemony.PlayerTurn"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.hegemony.PLAYERTURN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Java Code of sending activity:

```
public class SetupHomeScreen extends Activity{

private ArrayList<Player> p = GameMaster.players;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup_home_screen);
    getActionBar().hide();
    updatePlayers();
    Button gotoInput = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSetupPlayer);
    gotoInput.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent toInput = new Intent("com.example.hegemony.SETUPPLAYER");
            startActivity(toInput);
        }
    });

    Button startGame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartGame);
    startGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent toStart = new Intent("com.example.hegemony.PLAYERTURN");
            startActivity(toStart);
        }
    });

}


 public void updatePlayers(){
        TextView playerList = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playerList);
        String msg = "";
        for(int i=0;i < p.size();i++)
            msg = msg + "\n - "+p.get(i).getName();
        playerList.setText(msg);
        if(p.size() >=2){
            Button enable = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartGame);
            enable.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Java code of receiving activity:

```
public class PlayerTurn extends Activity {

final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_turn);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }

    }; 
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Button startGame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartGame);
    startGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent toStart = new Intent(SendingActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
            startActivity(toStart);
        }
    });
```

I think this is how you should start an intent. Maybe its missing a context or the "activityname" is not the right way to do it. I tried to start an activity the way you are trying and it gave me an error as well, not the same one, but it didn't work.
I'm sorry if the solution I'm trying to provide doesn't work. This is really the first time I'm trying to help someone. I hope it works.

Comment: I already tried that and it does not work. What error are you getting?

Comment: Activity not found exception. Okay, let me try to dig in more. What error does it give you if you try the way I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

As per the logcat error message, your activity class is failing to instantiate. Instantiation involves the allocation and assignment of any class member variables. In the case of PlayerTurn, the only one is this:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
```

The call to getActionBar() throws a NullPointerException because the activity's window has not been built yet - you should call getActionBar() after setContentView() has been called in onCreate(). You can resolve this by simply moving that line of code into onCreate().

If you still want to retain this as a class member variable, declare it but don't assign it:

```
ActionBar actionBar;
```

...and then do the assignment in onCreate():

```
actionBar = getActionBar();
```